# Saving application form details then re-open it

Tags: c#, save, minesweeper

i wrote a c# program of the minesweeper game, and my problem is saving the current grid status (enabled buttons, flags put etc...) so how can i save the grid so if the user exits the from suddenly while playing and end the program, he can start from his last save?

Comment: Generically, create a class to hold the names and values of the controls..  Populate it and use XML serialization to save it.  On form load, de-serialize and update your controls with the saved values.  Another option would be to create entries for all of those values you want to save in Project --> Properties --> Settings.  Update them when you close, and then reload them when the app is opened again.

Comment: The XML method will com in handy! Thank you!